# Update div when dropdown changes with data from SQL

Tags: php, sql

```
<select id="postnr" name="post_postnr" onChange="updatePlace()">
        <?php do { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_postnr['postnr'] ?>" ><?php echo $row_postnr['postnr']?></option>
        <?php } while ($row_postnr = mysql_fetch_assoc($postnr));?>
      </select>&ensp;<div id="place" style="display:inline"></div>
```

When user changes value in dropdown, I want to search a database (same table) for the corresponding place and paste it into innerHTML of `#place`.

The values for the dropdown is collected from a SQL table, column `postnr`.

```
postnr    place
-----------------
1234      Place1
3456      Place2
```

and so on...

So when 1234 is selected, Place1 should pop up next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Very basic question about the use of [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/).

`updatePlace()` should be a Javascript method that will make an AJAX request to a specific PHP page. This page have to connect to the database and get all needed values.

Take a look at [this sample](http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_ajax_database.asp) to have a clearer idea.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can use the following (the way to do it is the same without jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#postnr").on('change', function(){
    $.get('get_place.php', {postnr: postnr}, function(data){
        $("#place").html(data);
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Then create a *get_place.php* file with something like the following:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM places WHERE postnr='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['postnr'])."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $row['place'];
```